# UITableView inside popover will not scroll

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I am trying to fix someone's code and am running into a problem. Here is the situation:
I have a full screen UIViewController that has a bottom bar button. When I press that button, it shows a popup view controller in the bottom left of the screen. That view controller inside the popup also has a button, and when I press THAT button it pushes a new view controller into my popup window. That new view controller is a UITableView that can have some large number of elements. The problem is that when I try to scroll down to see some offscreen elements, the scroll bounces back to the first position in the table, i.e. it does not really scroll.

More specifically here is some code:

In FullScreenVC.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* stuffInList;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPopoverController *namePopover;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *nameNav;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIBarButtonItem* addButton;
```

Inside FullScreenVC buttonPressed (called when addButton is pressed):

```
FirstPopupVC *vc=[FirstPopupVC alloc] initWithNibName@"FirstPopupVC" bundle:nil];
vc.delegate=self;
vc.stuffInList=self.stuffInList; // This is just the NSArray of list items
self.nameNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc] autorelease];
self.namePopover = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] 
              initWithContentViewController:self.nameNav] autorelease];
[vc release];
[self.namePopover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.addButton
               permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

In other words, the FirstPopupVC object vc is the root view controller of a UINavigationViewController nameNav, and nameNav is the navigationcontroller that is the content inside the namePopover UIPopoverController. I think the last line launches FirstPopupVC as a popup from the addButton. Note also that the XIB file FirstPopupVC.xib is a simple NIB file that has a few simple views (label etc) and a little button that a user can press to get the second popup, as we'll see.

Inside FirstPopupVC we have:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // some other irrelevant initialization stuff here ...

        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 340);
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)littleButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    SecondPopupVC * secondVC=[[SecondPopupVC alloc] 
          initWithNibName:"@SimpleTableView" bundle"nil];
    secondVC.delegate=self;
    secondVC.stuffInList=self.stuffInList;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
    [secondVC release];
}
```

This of course presents the second view controller inside the popop.

Inside SecondPopupVC we have:

```
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 340);

    }
    return self;
}
```

Apparently the contentSizeForViewInPopover call here will set the size of the popover view with the table view. It looks like this is called inside initWithNibName in both the first and second view controllers.

So again, the problem is that if my listOfStuff is large, ie if the set of items in the table is large, then the table will not stay scrolled beyond the first visible set of rows. I can scroll down to see these items but as soon as I release the mouse pointer (on the emulator) or my finger (on the device), it bounces back to the top of the list.

I tried to add autoresizingmak code as discussed in [table view in popover is not scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292581/table-view-in-popover-is-not-scrolling) but that didn't work for me.

So how can I fix the above code so that my table stays scrolled when I try to scroll it?

Comment: Try `[secondVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,340)];` after `SecondPopupVC.stuffInList=self.stuffInList;`

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work. Still have the same problem. I even tried adding secondVC.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight) along with the setFrame and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that the problem has something to do with the fact that secondVC is created from a NIB file rather than programmatically. I tried doing this instead:

```
-(void)littleButtonClicked:(id)sender {
    SecondPopupVC * secondVC=[[SecondPopupVC alloc] init];
    CGSize contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 320);
    UIView* popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 
            contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];
    popoverView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
                                    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    UITableView *tblView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:popoverView.bounds];
    tblView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | 
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

    tblView.delegate = secondVC;
    tblView.dataSource = secondVC;
    tblView.rowHeight = 44;

    [popoverView addSubview:tblView];
    secondVC.view = popoverView;
    secondVC.contentSizeForViewInPopover = contentSize;
    secondVC.stuffInList=self.stuffInList;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
    [secondVC release];
}
```

and guess what? It works fine. So why would there be such a problem when SecondPopupVC is initialized from a NIB file rather than using code?